# Retrieve value of cell B assume that cell A has certain value (which A doesn't)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell A with some base value.
Cell B is a calculated function of A and some other variable (a complex chained one).

I want to set value of colum C like this:

```
C1 = value of B when A = 100
C2 = value of B when A = 101
C3 = value of B when A = 102
```

Assume that B is the result of complex chained calculation and it's not possible to copy the calculation from B into C.

Answer (score 0):

### Some Tricky ROW-INDEX-MATCH Combination

The formula is written to start in `C$1` and looking in column `A` and `B`. It is fairly obvious how to adjust to fit your needs. It might be better to choose a smaller range for efficiency i.e. instead of `A:A` to use `A$1:A$1000` and the same for the `B` column.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(100+ROW()-ROW(C$1)+1,A:A,0)),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(100+ROW()-ROW(A$1)+1,A:A,0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand your fomula. I don't need a range. Let me rephrase the question:  A1 & B1 are two fix cell. B1 = f(A1).  We have value C1, C2, C3 for A1 to take. Then we need to set D1 = B1 when A1 = C1;  D2 = B1 when A1 = C2;  etc...

Comment: @DuyAnhPham: Although I don't believe that that's it, from your comment I could only understand the following: '=IF(C1=A$1,B$1,"")' in cell 'D1' and copy down.